# Make Discord.py Bot Only Work In Specific Channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I was making a bot for my friend using discord.py
and I wanted to make it so that it would only work in channel which include the word ***ticket***, made by another bot named *Ticket Toll*

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Relevant docs on text channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#textchannel)

Unfortunately, Discord's API does not keep track of who created the channel (which is why there's no such thing as `channel.author`).

One solution would be to have *Ticket Toll* create channels in a category, and only give your bot permissions to view this category.

However, you can easily have the bot ignore messages if the channel doesn't have *"ticket"* in the name, by checking `channel.name`. Here's an example with the `on_message` event:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'ticket' not in message.channel.name: return
    # stuff to execute if message was sent in a channel with ticket in its name
```

Or as a command:

```
@client.command()
async def something(ctx, arg):
    if "ticket" not in ctx.message.channel.name: return
    # stuff to execute if the command was sent in a channel with ticket in its name
```

Answer (score 0):

Only give the bot access to read channels where you want it to work.